# What markup/markdown is used for formatting Dart's changelog.md file

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

What markup/markdown can be used for dart's changlog.md styling?
I am aware of

- Wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Cheatsheet
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/markdown

Is there a recommended markup/markdown specifically for the changelog.md?

Comment: I think you should clarify your question. What are you actually trying to accomplish. AFAIK pub.dartlang.org is built with Python not Dart.

Comment: Hi Gunter. Happy New Year! I now use StageHand to create my dart project. It also creates a changelog.md file with the following contents |# Changelog

## 0.0.1

* Initial version, created by Stagehand.
| The hash and asterisk look like some markup/markdown is being used. I would like to know what tool is used for the interpretation of the markup so I can format the changelog.md file. Thanks.

Comment: Happy new year. I guess its https://github.com/dart-lang/py-gfm. See also https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/